# Index using a forloop in matlab

Tags: matlab, for-loop, indexing, cell

I am trying to index each string from a 30x1 cell in MATLAB using a for loop.  I know how to index it `text{1,1}` I am just unsure how to set it up in a for loop.

Answer (score 2):

```
for index=1:30
    text{index,1}
end
```

Something like that should work. Could also replace 30 with size determined dynamically --

```
for index=1:size(text,1)
```

i think, since you want the size along the first dimension... haven't coded Matlab in a while sorry!